# url rewriting to virtual path keeping always the virtual path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

I have a physical folder:

```
http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/
```

and I want that all requests to `http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/*` and `http://www.myowndomain.com/path2/*` (that is a virtual folder, it doesn't exists) will be redirected to `http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/*`. Moreover I want all those requests show in the url bar

```
http://www.myowndomain.com/path2/*
```

Where should I put `.htaccess` file and what would it be its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to you /root.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)externally Redirect /path1/* => /path2/*##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /path1/(.*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /path2/%1 [NE,L,R]
#2)internally Redirect /path2/* => /path1/*##
RewriteRule ^/?path2/(.*)$ /path1/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect **/path2/** to **/path1** .

Comment: doesn't work. http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/ shows in address bar http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/ instead of http://www.myowndomain.com/path2/ as requested. 
http://www.myowndomain.com/path2/ shows in the address bar http://www.myowndomain.com/path1/ instead of http://www.myowndomain.com/path2/ as requested